# how good is selenium's support for https and automatic cookie handling?

Tags: java, selenium

How good is selenium's support for https and also for automatically reading, writing, and discarding of cookies- using a java implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its good actually, I did not face any problems while using https sites using selenium. You might face few issues if working on different domain (ex. http://example.com to https://example1.com), but other than that its pretty good.

There are lot of methods available to work with cookies. for ex:

- createCookie(java.lang.String nameValuePair, java.lang.String optionsString)
  Create a new cookie whose path and domain are same with those of current page under test, unless you specified a path for this cookie explicitly.
- deleteAllVisibleCookies()
  Calls deleteCookie with recurse=true on all cookies visible to the current page.
- deleteCookie(java.lang.String name, java.lang.String optionsString)
  Delete a named cookie with specified path and domain.
- getCookie()
  Return all cookies of the current page under test.
- getCookieByName(java.lang.String name)
  Returns the value of the cookie with the specified name, or throws an error if the cookie is not present.
- isCookiePresent(java.lang.String name)
  Returns true if a cookie with the specified name is present, or false otherwise.